# Data Binding - How to write multi-line declarations?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Is there any way to write multi-line code with DataBinding library?

I tried following, but it complains about XML format

```
android:text="@{
            viewModel.subscriptionExpiration == null
                ? viewModel.field1
                : viewModel.field2
        }"
```

With following error: `Error:(80) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)`

Single-line alternative works, but I find it less readable:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.subscriptionExpiration == null ? viewModel.field1 : viewModel.field2}"
```

Comment: Any luck?  We are interested in this as well.

Comment: @nAndroid I still did not found a solution for DataBinding, but you can check my latest answer on this question below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried doing some digging and couldn't find an answer. I don't know that you can break up string literals that way in xml. As an alternative I would recommend offloading the evaluation to the viewModel instead, in the form of:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.subscriptionStatus}"
```

then in your viewModel class

```
@Bindable
public String getSubscriptionStatus(){
    return getSubscriptionExpiration() == null
            ? getField1()
            : getField2();
}
```

Comment: What if I have to do some UI-related stuff?

Comment: I would suggest limiting your models to modeling the view's state. If you need to handle clicks or other ui events you can pass the ViewDataBinding some kind of handler interface and have that deal with the UI events. If you need data from  one passed into the other you can specify that in the binding as well since you have references to both the handler and the model.

It might look like this:

<data>
    <variable name="model" type="ViewModel" />
    <variable name="handler" type="Presenter" />
</data>